# Editfield dynamic

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I used the below code  for edit text where I give the width and the height  for  the edit text and once the text fills the given height the field will scroll its content, but I want to make this code  more dynamic. I want this editfield with only one line and  it will grow for a  number of lines done 3 or 4 and after this is done the field should scroll what it contains. Any help with that?

```
public class TextBoxField extends VerticalFieldManager {
    private int managerWidth;
    private int managerHeight;
    private EditField editField;

    public TextBoxField(int width, int height) {
        super(Manager.NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        managerWidth = width;
        managerHeight = height;

        VerticalFieldManager vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);

        editField = new EditField(){
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
            getManager().invalidate();
            super.paint(g);
        }
    };

    vfm.add(editField);
        add(vfm);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

    public void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        if (managerWidth == 0) {
            managerWidth = width;
        }
        if (managerHeight == 0) {
            managerHeight = height;
        }
        super.sublayout(managerWidth, managerHeight);
        setExtent(managerWidth,managerHeight);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return editField.getText();
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        editField.setText(text);
    }
}
```